# Sorting listview by WORD from sql lite

Tags: android, listview

hi, guys! I would like a help. How to sorting my entries in a ListView Activity from sql db by word, instead of id_key? This is a  personal dictionary app

I'm a newbie.

DictionaryDataHelper

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DictionaryDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

final static String DICTIONARY_DATABASE="dictionary";
final static String ITEM_ID_COLUMN="id";
final static String WORD_COLUMN="word";
final static String DEFINITION_COLUMN="definition";


final static String CREATE_DATABASE_QUERY="CREATE TABLE "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE+" ( "+
ITEM_ID_COLUMN+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
WORD_COLUMN+" TEXT , "+
DEFINITION_COLUMN+" TEXT)";


final static String ON_UPGRADE_QUERY="DROP TABLE "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE;

Context context;


public DictionaryDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DICTIONARY_DATABASE, factory, version);
    this.context=context;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_QUERY);    
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    database.execSQL(ON_UPGRADE_QUERY);
    onCreate(database);

}

public long insertData(WordDefinition wordDefinition) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(WORD_COLUMN, wordDefinition.word);
    values.put(DEFINITION_COLUMN, wordDefinition.definition);

    return database.insert(DICTIONARY_DATABASE, null, values);      

}

public long updateData(WordDefinition wordDefinition) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(WORD_COLUMN, wordDefinition.word);
    values.put(DEFINITION_COLUMN, wordDefinition.definition);

    return database.update(DICTIONARY_DATABASE, values, WORD_COLUMN+" =?", new String[]{wordDefinition.word});  

}

public void deleteData(WordDefinition wordDefinition) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String queryString="DELETE FROM "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE+" WHERE "+WORD_COLUMN+" = '"+wordDefinition.word+"'";

    database.execSQL(queryString);
}

public ArrayList<WordDefinition> getAllWords() {
    ArrayList<WordDefinition> arrayList=new ArrayList<WordDefinition>();
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectAllQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE;
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectAllQueryString, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {            
            WordDefinition wordDefinition=new WordDefinition(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_COLUMN)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DEFINITION_COLUMN)));
            arrayList.add(wordDefinition);              
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());          
    }   
    return arrayList;
}

public WordDefinition getWordDefinition(String word) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getReadableDatabase();
    WordDefinition wordDefinition=null;

    String selectQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE+ " WHERE "+WORD_COLUMN+" = '"+word+ "'";
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectQueryString, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        wordDefinition=new WordDefinition(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_COLUMN)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DEFINITION_COLUMN)));

    }   

    return wordDefinition;

}

public WordDefinition getWordDefinition(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getReadableDatabase();
    WordDefinition wordDefinition=null;

    String selectQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE+ " WHERE "+ITEM_ID_COLUMN+" = '"+id+ "'";
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectQueryString, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        wordDefinition=new WordDefinition(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_COLUMN)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DEFINITION_COLUMN)));

    }   

    return wordDefinition;

}

public void initializeDatabaseFortheFirstTime(ArrayList<WordDefinition> wordDefinitions) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL("BEGIN");

    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

    for (WordDefinition wordDefinition : wordDefinitions) {
        contentValues.put(WORD_COLUMN, wordDefinition.word);
        contentValues.put(DEFINITION_COLUMN, wordDefinition.definition);            
        database.insert(DICTIONARY_DATABASE, null, contentValues);
    }
    database.execSQL("COMMIT");

}


}
```

DictionaryListActivity

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DictionaryListActivity extends Activity {

TextView userTextView;
EditText searchEditText;
Button searchButton;
ListView dictionaryListView;

String logTagString="DICTIONARY";
ArrayList<WordDefinition> allWordDefinitions=new ArrayList<WordDefinition>();


DictionaryDatabaseHelper myDictionaryDatabaseHelper;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionary_list);

    Log.d("DICTIONARY", "second activity started");


    userTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.personTextView);
    userTextView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.USER_NAME_STRING));

    searchEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
    searchButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    dictionaryListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.dictionaryListView);

    myDictionaryDatabaseHelper=new DictionaryDatabaseHelper(this, "Dictionary", null, 1);
    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.SHARED_NAME_STRING, MODE_PRIVATE);


    boolean initialized=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("initialized", false);

    if (initialized==false) {
        //Log.d(logTagString, "initializing for the first time");
        initializeDatabase();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("initialized", true);
        editor.commit();

    }else {
        Log.d(logTagString, "db already initialized");
    }

    allWordDefinitions=myDictionaryDatabaseHelper.getAllWords();

    dictionaryListView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
            if (view==null) {
                view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }
            TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listItemTextView);
            textView.setText(allWordDefinitions.get(position).word);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return allWordDefinitions.size();
        }
    });

    dictionaryListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
            Intent intent =new Intent(DictionaryListActivity.this, WordDefinitionDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("word", allWordDefinitions.get(position).word);
            intent.putExtra("definition", allWordDefinitions.get(position).definition);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String string=searchEditText.getText().toString();

            WordDefinition wordDefinition=myDictionaryDatabaseHelper.getWordDefinition(string);

            if (wordDefinition==null) {
                Toast.makeText(DictionaryListActivity.this, "Expressão não encontrada.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Intent intent =new Intent(DictionaryListActivity.this, WordDefinitionDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("word", wordDefinition.word);
                intent.putExtra("definition", wordDefinition.definition);

                startActivity(intent);
            }


        }
    });




}

//


private void initializeDatabase() {
    InputStream inputStream=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dictionary);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    DictionaryLoader.loadData(bufferedReader, myDictionaryDatabaseHelper);

}

}
```

DictionaryLoader

```
package com.ecidioms;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collections;
 import java.util.Comparator;

 public class DictionaryLoader implements Comparator<WordDefinition> {

 @Override
 public int compare(WordDefinition A, WordDefinition B) {
    return A.compareTo(B);
}

public static void loadData(BufferedReader bufferedReader, DictionaryDatabaseHelper dictionaryDatabaseHelper) {

    ArrayList<WordDefinition> allWords=new ArrayList<WordDefinition>();
    Collections.sort(allWords, new DictionaryLoader());

    try {

        BufferedReader fileReader=bufferedReader;

        try {

            int c=17;
            c=fileReader.read();
            while (c!=(-1)) {

                StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();

                while ((char)c!='\n'&&c!=-1) {
                    try {
                        stringBuilder.append((char)c);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.println(stringBuilder.length());
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    c= fileReader.read();
                    if (c==-1) {
                        return;
                    }
                }


                String wordString=stringBuilder.toString();

                ArrayList<String> definition=new ArrayList<String>();
                while (c=='\n'||c=='\t') {
                    c= fileReader.read();
                    if (c=='\n'||c=='\t'||c=='\r') {
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder2=new StringBuilder();
                        while (c!='\n') {
                            stringBuilder2.append((char)c);
                            c=fileReader.read();
                        }
                        String definitionString=stringBuilder2.toString();
                        definition.add(definitionString);
                    }else {
                        break;
                    }

                }

                wordString=wordString.trim();
                //Logger.log("word Loaded: "+(++counter)+" :"+wordString);
                allWords.add(new WordDefinition(wordString, definition));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            dictionaryDatabaseHelper.initializeDatabaseFortheFirstTime(allWords);
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

WordDefinition

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordDefinition {
String word,definition;

public WordDefinition(String word,ArrayList<String> alldefinition) {
    this.word=word;

    StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
    for (String string : alldefinition) {
        stringBuilder.append(string);
    }       
    this.definition=stringBuilder.toString();

}

public WordDefinition(String word,String alldefinition) {
    this.word=word;     
    this.definition=alldefinition;

}


}
```

WordDefinitionDetailActivity

```
import com.ecidioms.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WordDefinitionDetailActivity extends Activity {

TextView wordTextView;
TextView definitionTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_word_definition_detail);
    wordTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.wordTextView);
    definitionTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.definitionTextView);

    Log.d("DICTIONARY", "third activity started");



    wordTextView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("word"));
    definitionTextView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("definition"));

   }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.word_definition_detail, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: `ORDER BY word` in your sql query.

Comment: @njzk2 I think I should put "order by word" in DictionaryDatabaseHelper activity, but which part of the code? i'm a newbie and I'm confused.

Comment: `in your sql query.` Specifically, in the select query that you make, `selectAllQueryString`

Comment: @njzk2 It didn't work. I tried: String selectAllQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE;
  Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectAllQueryString, WORD_COLUMN + " ASC", null);   but a redmark under "rawQuery" says: remove argument to match 'rawQuery'

Comment: yeah, like I said, add ` ORDER BY word` to `selectAllQueryString`.

Comment: Oh, that's right. It worked. Thanks!!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to sort all your WordDefinitions would be to create a Custom Comparator like this:

```
class DefinitionComparator implements Comparator<WordDefinition> {

@Override
public int compareTo(WordDefinition this, WordDefinition that) {
    return this.getWord().compareTo(that.getWord());
    }
}
```

And then pass a new instance of your custom comparator to a the Collections.sort method with your returned ArrayList(from the database) like this:

```
Collections.sort(myWordDefinitionList, this);
```

**EDIT:**

So you need to add word and definition getters in your WordDefinition class:

```
public String getWord() {
    return this.word;
}

public String getDefinition() {
    return this.definition;
}
```

Comment: Which Activity of my project I must put this, @andrewdleach?

Comment: It looks like Dictionary Loader is your best bet if you don;t want too much pressure on your sqlite calls, but you could do this to the ArrayList you return to the calling code each time in the getAllWords() method

Comment: It didn't work... I'll update how I did it. Check Dictionary Loader above. I did changes into the code box.

Comment: Pass in a reference to 'this' instead of a new instance of the Comparator since you implement Comparator in the DictionaryLoader class.

Comment: Man, sorry, I've tried, but they ask to create a method called getWord() :(! I can't understand. Could you help me by put what you explained in my DictionaryLoader (because I'm newbie and I didn't get it yet, please?)

Comment: What are the methods in your Word definition object? It looks like you pass two paras to the constructor.  Do you have any getters? The getWord () call was my interpretation of the word definition class

Comment: There it is, andrewdleach!! I added the others two activities: WordDefinition and WordDefinitionDetailActivity above.

Comment: I added  word and definition getters in my WordDefinition class and the entries words in a ListView it was not sorted by alphabetical order :/ . It didn't work. But thanks for everything.